# how to add centre nav with condition for few pages in existing left navigation bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

for few pages I want centre navigation bar along with left navigation bar  how should left and center navigation bar limited for few pages only.
      how to adjust left and center navigation bar for restricted pages in single layout page.

Comment: Add pagination HTML.

Comment: could you please provide me coding example

Comment: Could your please provide a code?

Comment: As per my knowledge ,I couldn't achieve left and center navigation bar for few pages and only left navigation bar for remaining pages.I had to use two different layout.gsp (here I am using bootstrap and groovy)